# Schedule Task - cron task or other schedule options - every 15 seconds - Coldfusion

Tags: windows, coldfusion, cron

I need to figure a way to create a schedule task that runs every 15 seconds.
Coldfusion schedule task only run every 60 seconds - Not sure if I can change that to run very 15 seconds.

I can use a 3rd party tool or the built in windows application to do this but I can not figure out a way to set up a task that run quicker then 60 seconds.

Comment: Try using a meta refresh.

Comment: I noticed many CRON questions on SO recommend using "sleep" in the task to delay & offset execution time. Schedule 4 different tasks for each minute and have #2 sleep for 15 seconds, #3 sleep for 30 seconds and #4 for 45 seconds.

Comment: Just be sure to handle the possibility of overlaps if the tasks take longer than expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set cron for less than one minute.  There is a workaround:

- Shell Script (infinite iteration / loop through with sleep).